# to get the form data from multiple checkbox

Tags: php

As i want to get the form data and want to process that data and store into database..I am getting all checked box values but i am enable to get the text value although i used $_POST['text-name'] in the code...Please help me to get the
error..My code is Below

```
 if(isset($_POST['give-score'])&&!empty($_POST['checked'])){
        $employeedetails  = $_POST['checked'];
        $score = $_POST['score'];
        $username = $employeedetails[1];
        $workname = $employeedetails[2];
        changeworkstatus($username,$workname,$con);
        $workname  = $employeedetails[2];
        addscorepoints($workname,$score,$con);
}else{
    echo "";
}
```

and my form html code is below

```
   <td><input type="checkbox"  name="checked[]" id="employeework" value="" style="align: center"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" id="employeework"value="<?php  echo $results['username']; ?>"><?php  echo $results['username']; ?></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" id="employeework"value="<?php echo $results['work_name'];?>"><?php echo $results['work_name'];?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="score" id="score" placeholder="Your Score Here"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="give-score"></td>
```

php part used in the table are working fine..but the **input[type=text]** i am not getting that value..

Comment: From what is visible in the code you posted, there is nothing wrong. If the form contains `name="score"` and is being sent with _POST_, then `$_POST['score']` should exist. Have you tried a `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: yes it gets string(0)..

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays index starts from 0 not 1. then you must change this lines:

```
$username = $employeedetails[0];
$workname = $employeedetails[1];
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: i am just omitting the first check box value...i need  value from the second checkbox so i write the code like that :) @mimrahe

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in your code even then I am providing the following code which I've tried. I am getting all values from the form elements.

Code of the html file

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="POST"> Checked value:
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" id="t1" value="test1">test1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" id="t2" value="test2">test2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" id="t3" value="test3">test3</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="score" id="score" placeholder="Your Score Here">        </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="give-score"></td>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of PHP file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['give-score'])&&!empty($_POST['checked'])){
$employeedetails  = $_POST['checked'];
echo $score = $_POST['score']."<br>";
echo $username = $employeedetails[0]."<br>";
echo $workname = $employeedetails[1]."<br>";
echo $workname = $employeedetails[2]."<br>";
}else{
echo "No data found";
}
?>
```

I hope this will help you!